# Proportional stratified random sample in Google Earth Engine - setting class point and class value lists from histogram dictionary

Tags: google-earth-engine

How do I perform a stratified random sample on a classified image where the number of points are based on 1% of class pixels up to 500 points?

I've developed strata with unsupervised classification and ran a histogram reducer to get a pixel count per class. I'd like to map over the dictionary values with an algorithm; if(value/100)<500, then value/100, otherwise 500. Then convert the output dictionary to two lists to feed to "classValues:" "classPoints:" in .stratifiedSample().

I'm stuck at mapping over the dictionary and extracting two lists from the dictionary. I'm open to easier methods.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/bb073e42d90b0544723d1af623df13a9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need (and should never use) `ee.Algorithms.If()`

```
var scale = function (key, value) {
  return ee.Number(value).divide(100).min(500).int()
};
```

And second, you just need to get the keys() and values() from the dictionary for the two lists.  (Plus a couple of casts and a get).

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6a2de7f80833da9942cb583b605694a6

Comment: Thank you so much!!